# GraphQL schema definition - Can encapsulate object in a Input/Type?

Tags: input, types, graphql

Can I encapsulate object in an Input/Type? Assuming that we have this schema definition :

```
input MyChildInput {
  territoryId: String!
  mapsTo: [String!]!
}

input MyInput {
  uuid: ID!
  childInput: [MyChildInput!]!
}
```

I would like to have something like the code bellow, is it even possible ?

```
input MyInput {
  uuid: ID!
  childInput: [{
    territoryId: String!
    mapsTo: [String!]!
  }!]!
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GraphlQL does not support anonymous types. All object types in GraphQL need to have a name.

Having named types has a lot of benefits. It allows type reuse, it also makes it possible to apply fragments against them. Type names are also used by various GraphQL clients to cache data fetched from the API.